# Iterative deepening with Max depth constraint in Prolog

Tags: prolog, shortest-path

I have to modify the following Prolog program that implements the iterative deepening dfs search on a graph:

```
s(a, b).
s(b, c).
s(c, d).
s(a, d).

goal(d).

/* Solution is the inverse list of the visited node 
           from the start node Node and a goal node
           if it is TRUE that:

   path/3 predicate is TRUE (Solution is the inverse list 
           from the start node Node and a GoalNode)
           and it is TRUE that GoalNode is a goal 
*/
depth_first_iterative_deepening(Node, Solution) :- 
    path(Node, GoalNode, Solution),
    goal(GoalNode).

/* Path/3 predicate generate, for the given initial node, 
           all the possibles acyclic paths of increasing
           length
*/

/* BASE CASE: The shorter path from a node X to itself is Path=[X] */
path(Node, Node, [Node]).

/* GENERAL CASE: If I have to go from a start node X 
           to an end node Y and X != Y
   [LastNode|Path] is the path from FirstNode and LastNode 
           if it is TRUE that:

   1) Path is the path from FirstNode and OneButLast node
   2) Exist an edge from OneButLast and LastNode
   3) I have yet never visited LastNode
*/
path(FirstNode, LastNode, [LastNode|Path]) :- 
    path(FirstNode, OneButLast, Path),
    s(OneButLast, LastNode),
    not(member(LastNode, Path)).
```

The **`path/3`** predicate **generates, for the given initial node, all the possibles acyclic paths of increasing length** so using the **`depth_first_iterative_deepening/2`** predicate I generate all the solution from the start node to the end node ordered by length (from the shortest one to the longest one).

Ok, so I have to modify this program **in such a way that imposes a limit on the length of the solution**

I must have a **`depth_first_iterative_deepening2/3`** predicate like this:

```
depth_first_iterative_deepening2(Node, Max, Solution)
```

where `Max` is the maximum number of the visited node so that `Solution` is acceptable.

so `Solution` is the solution path from the start node `Node` to a goal node if `Solution` length is minor or equal of `Max` value.

I have tried to do this change in the previous predicate but it have some problems and don't work well:

```
depth_first_iterative_deepening2(Node, Max, Solution) :- 
    path2(Node, GoalNode, Solution),
    goal(GoalNode),
    length(Solution, Length),
    write(Length),
    (Length =< Max).
```

How you can see when it calculate a `Solution` (using the **`path2/3`** predicate) that bring into a goal node, I put into Length variable the length of this solution and **I impose that the length of this solution must be less than or equal to the value of the variable `Max`**

The problem is that if the solution found is ok (its length is `<=` the `Max` value) it work well but if the solution found it is not ok (have length `>` then the `Max` value) go into error:

```
[debug]  ?- depth_first_iterative_deepening2(a,1,Solution).
24
ERROR: Out of local stack
   Exception: (1,597,352) path2(a, _G4793274, _G4792038) ?
```

Looking to the trace it seems that the problem is that when **`(Length =< Max)`** fails it recalls again the **`path2/3`** predicate to find another solution (that it is the same because `path2/3`  always finds the shortest path to the first call, so it will find the same solution that bring into a fail)

I would like that if the **`(Length =< Max)`** check fails, then **`depth_first_iterative_deepening2/3`** have to fail

Can I use the cut to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try

```
( (Length =< Max) ; (Length > Max), !, fail).
```

instead of

```
(Length =< Max).
```

Comment: It work...now it is much clear: both if have found a valid solution or not found it, at the end fail and quit the program !!!

Comment: @AndreaNobili yes; when length =< max, we must allow for user to backtrack. Hence the mutually-exclusive guard in the second  alternative.

Answer (score 0):

That's the same 'trick' I proposed some time ago.

Place the test *before* to call the visit:

```
depth_first_iterative_deepening2(Node, Max, Solution) :-
   length(Solution, Length),
   Length =< Max,
   path2(Node, GoalNode, Solution),
   goal(GoalNode).
```

Comment: I had tryed it before ask here, but still don't work: the cursor blinks and don't comes to the conclusion false